# Creating a Foreign Key relationship in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm beginning with Mongoose and I want to know how to do this type of configuration:

[image]

A recipe has different ingredients.

I have my two models:

Ingredient and Recipe:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var IngredientSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ingredient', IngredientSchema);
```

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);
```

Comment: I guess you are asking how to use Ref operator?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Check Updated code below, in particular this part:
`{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient'}`

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var IngredientSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ingredient', IngredientSchema);
```

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    ingredients:[
      {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient'}
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);
```

**To Save:**

```js
var r = new Recipe();

r.name = 'Blah';
r.ingredients.push('mongo id of ingredient');

r.save();
```

Comment: How am I saving ? for this moment, I am saving like this :

 .post(function(req, res) {
        var recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.name = req.body.name;
        recipe.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'recipe created' });
        });
    })

Comment: You would need to save ingredients separately and then push id into array.

Comment: I tried this: `var ChildSchema = new Schema({ name: String }); mongoose.model('Child', ChildSchema); var ParentSchema = new Schema({ name: String, children: [{ childId: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Child', required: true } }] }); mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema);`. When I push the child into the parent document, like this: `parent.locations.push({ childId: child.id });parent.save();`, the document looks like this: `{ "name" : "Bob", "children" : [ { "childId" : ObjectId("57769de13eaeda6020b522f2"), "_id" : ObjectId("5776a23a511539a421824c27") } ] }`. Why is there both a `childId` and an `id`?

Comment: @Web User You can either replace childId with _id or in your schema: .... children: [_id:false, { childId: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Child', required: true } }] I hope this helps

Comment: @Tim Because `child` has its own collection, I couldn't disable `_id` in `ChildSchema`. I created a new schema just to specify `{ _id: false }`, not knowing use of `_id` can be disabled right there while specifying the structure for `children`. Can you *please* help me with this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155298/how-to-update-mongodb-documents-with-arrays-of-sub-documents) I posted? Long story short, I am dealing with a schema that contains an array of sub-document which in turn contain an array of sub-documents. I need to add/update/delete at both levels. Thanks!

Comment: How it's possible to find the ingredient name object inside recipe object with  find query ? Could you showing an example with a find query please ?

Comment: @John there are multiple way of doing that, John just post another question post a link here and I will try to answer it since this comments thread getting bigger. Thanks

Comment: I did a post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575393/mongoose-multiple-synchronous-find-to-reuse-object-id

Comment: I guess the two schemas are in the same files, right?

Comment: @jsh6303 Can be in the same file can be in different files does not really matter. As long as it defined and included

Comment: and if you do r.ingredients.push() many times with the same foreign key, is this possible?

Comment: @OlivierPons Yes it should not be a problem

Comment: @Tim Sorry I didn't express myself: if I want to be able to have only once the same ingredient, and I want `r.ingredients.push()` twice with the same ingredient to be a problem (actually), how would you deal with this?

Comment: @OlivierPons you can have validation inside mongoose model.pre('save'), but that would not be atomic, another approach is to create unique index on subdocument see this article http://joegornick.com/2012/10/25/mongodb-unique-indexes-on-single-embedded-documents/ I hope this helps

Comment: does this method do validation of that foreign key i.e the _id in the schema with a "ref" property, should actually point to the referenced Model and ensure that the referenced Model contains exactly the same

Comment: No it does not validate, but you can validate on pre and post hooks