# Mongoose multiple synchronous find to reuse object ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

My models has lot of relationship between each object and when I want to search some data I have to find the previous object and it makes me to write lot of callback.

I have 4 models :

1. **Company**: Just one field, the company name field
2. **Geolocation**: Two field, latitude / longitude
3. **Office**: name, address and two ObjectID : Geolocation Object ID and Company Object ID
4. **User**: email, password etc... and the Office Object ID

Then I need to get the nearest users with their informations ( name, office name, company, name etc... ) by latitude / longitude. And here is the result callback from hell.

```
    // Find all Geolocation
    Geolocation.find({}, function(err, geolocations) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var array = [];

        // Loop on geolocations object
        Async.each(geolocations, function(origin, callback){

            var myJson = {"latitude":43.686978, "longitude":7.201922};

            // Calculate distance between two points
            var geo = geolib.getDistance(
                {latitude: origin.latitude, longitude: origin.longitude},
                {latitude: myJson.latitude, longitude: myJson.longitude}
            );

            // Find the office with the current geolocation object ID
            Office.findOne({ geolocation: origin._id}, function(err, office){
                if (err) throw err;

                // Find the company with the current office object ID
                Company.findOne({ _id: office.company }, function(err, company){
                    if (err) throw err;

                    // Find the user with the current office object ID
                    User.findOne({office: office._id}, function(err, user){
                        if (err) throw err;

                        array.push({
                            user: user.firstname+' '+user.lastname,
                            office: office.name,
                            company: company.name,
                            distance: geo
                        });

                        callback();
                    });
                });
            });

        }, function(err) {
            array.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.distance - b.distance;
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                console.log(array[i])
            }
        });

    });
```

I'm using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) but I don't know if it's the good way to know when the loop is finished and if the `each()` method is the most most appropriate.

As you can see I have to make lot of find to get the Object ID and find again to get all informations by users.

Do you have an idea to make my code cleaner ? Or maybe I shouldn't use object ID in my models ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each `findOne` function into the promise and use `await` from Babel. In this case, your code may look like this:

```
let office = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Office.findOne({ geolocation: origin._id}, function(err, office){
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve(office)
});

let company = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Company.findOne({ _id: office.company }, function(err, company){
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve(company)
});
... and so on
```

Or, maybe you want to read about population in MongoDB: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: The populate function can returns the Object needed directly ? It seems to be nice. But how can we do 2 populate ? Because I have two object ID in once model ?

Comment: You can populate 2 or more fields at the same time. Just do it like this `Story`
`.find(...)`
`.populate('fans _creator') // space delimited path names`
`.exec()`