# using ObjectId as a data type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a schema for an object and I'm using ObjectId as type but he gives me an error

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const permissionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  roleId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  menuPageId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  readAccess: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
  createAccess: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
  editAccess: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
  },
  deleteAccess: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
  },
});

const Permissions = mongoose.model("Permissions", permissionsSchema);
module.exports = Permissions;
```

**ERROR**

> type: ObjectId,
> ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ObjectId` with

```
mongoose.ObjectId
```

Or

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId
```

---

**Reference**

[Mongoose - ObjectIds](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids)

Comment: it's working thank you, so now I can store on it an ID for another object, it will work as a foreign key??

Comment: Hi, this question: [Creating a Foreign Key relationship in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26008555/8017690) maybe is what you need.